# CRM 2011 outlook client: Some entities are not available after changing the user language

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Error: cannot load crm when trying to view crm records for contact/accounts in outlook 2010

EDIT: I found out that this problem occurred because of the selected language by the user. Now i still have to find out how to solve this problem so that the user can keep his language.

Original question:

A customer of our company recent did the migration from CRM 4.0 to CRM 2011. First everything worked perfect but after a few days, one of the crm users could not see the records for accounts and contacts in his outlook client. A few days later, another user noticed the same error.

When they try to view the records for certain entities. No records are shown in de window. Only a message: "CRM cannot be loaded" (translated from dutch, i don't know the exact message in english).
Other entity records are shown perfect.

They tried already reinstalling the outlook client en reconfigureing there organisation in outlook.

When i open their organistation in my outlook, everything works just fine.

They are using outlook 2010 and me too.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: When i login in outlook crm with his user, i have the same problem. So it's user specific problem. Both users have the system administrator role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is some issues with the language used by the specific user? I earlier had a similar problem with an installation where English was used as base language - and the Norwegian language pack added later. Try to switch to English for the user who experiences these problems. If it helps you have a little translating to do.

Comment: It's possible, they had another language installed. I tried to change there language back to the base language (english) but that did not solved the problem. Unfortunatly, i had to create new users in AD and also in CRM and then assign the records to these new users to solve my problem.

Comment: Hi, the problem is indeed the language! I just received a call from our customer that after he changed the language to dutch, his contacts & accounts failed to load in outlook. How did you solved this exactly?

Comment: Here's how i finally solved this problem. 1. Export all translations (Settings/Customizations/Customize the system) 2. Open the exel file and make sure every cell under the desired language code has a value. 3. Save the exel file. 4. Import the translations back to CRM 5. Problem Solved!